# How to make startx open new X Session in tty7 on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: xorg, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Before, when I launched x from the tty1 console, it would start the x session in tty7, allowing me to terminate it easily from tty1. Now (I do not know what changed it), startx from tty1 will open X in tty1. How can I change it so it will open in tty7? (I'm running Raspbian Jessie)

Comment: Certain changes came with Jessie, one being kernel-based video controls, I forget the technical name, but basically, X11 is run as user on own tty, vs as root on some other tty.  It works great overall, just a bit surprising when you're used to the old behavior.  Perhaps someone could elaborate more on this.  I haven't really ever used my RPi's with a keyboard, always accessed them through ssh. (Although I wrote [fauxcon (github)](https://github.com/lornix/fauxcon)  to _pretend_ I was using the keyboard though!)

Comment: Quick question: are you able to launch x remotely on your client through ssh?

Comment: I have done in the past, although I generally strip out most of the X stuff, the RPi aren't beefy enough to run a Desktop Environment **and** server-type operations without some stuttering and issues.  Anything that remains is displayed on my laptop through X11-Forwarding, so again, no X framework running on the RPi's.  To answer your question:  Yes, I have been able to launch X remotely through ssh.  BUT am not able to do so at this time due to removal of X **server** framework on RPi's.